# All of a sudden my page is throwing me 404 error

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Hi I have a page hosted at my

```
username.github.com
```

But all of sudden this page is throwing me an 404 error message. I'm not sure what went wrong. But the thing is its not working!

Are there any one who faced the same situation and solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be related to recent [GitHub issues](https://status.github.com/):

```
October 22, 2012 – minor interruption occurred

02:17 pm PST
The status website is misreporting availability of services again.  
Git and Downloads are both available.
```

---

Note: [since April 2013](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages), that would be username.github.io